# Decrement the value of a variable at every function call

Tags: javascript

I am creating a slot machine program using JavaScript, and want to decrement the value of coins at every function call. For example, `coins = 20`. It should decrement after every time the `casino()` function is called. Basically the function can be called as many times until `coins = 0`.
Is this a situation where the application of `let` vs `var` comes into play?
Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
let reel1 = ["cherry", "lemon", "apple", "lemon", "banana", "banana", "lemon", "lemon"]
let reel2 = ["lemon", "apple", "lemon", "lemon", "cherry", "apple", "banana", "lemon"]
let reel3 = ["lemon", "apple", "lemon", "apple", "cherry", "lemon", "banana", "lemon"]
let slotReel = []
let coins = 20

function casino(r1, r2, r3) {
  coins = coins - 1
  
  let random1 = reel1[Math.floor(Math.random() * reel1.length)]
  let random2 = reel2[Math.floor(Math.random() * reel3.length)]
  let random3 = reel3[Math.floor(Math.random() * reel3.length)]
  
  slotReel.push(random1, random2, random3)
  //.....some logic
}

casino(reel1, reel2, reel3);
console.log("Coins after running the function:", coins);
```

Comment: Is something not working? Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: The value of `coins` becomes 20 after the function is run everytime.

Comment: Evidently it doesn’t. [Edit] your post and provide a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

You need create a loop to call the function until the coins are gone.

```js
let reel1 = ["cherry", "lemon", "apple", "lemon", "banana", "banana", "lemon", "lemon"]
let reel2 = ["lemon", "apple", "lemon", "lemon", "cherry", "apple", "banana", "lemon"]
let reel3 = ["lemon", "apple", "lemon", "apple", "cherry", "lemon", "banana", "lemon"]
let slotReel = []
let coins = 20;

function casino(r1, r2, r3) {
    let random1 = reel1[Math.floor(Math.random() * reel1.length)]
    let random2 = reel2[Math.floor(Math.random() * reel3.length)]
    let random3 = reel3[Math.floor(Math.random() * reel3.length)]
    slotReel.push(random1, random2, random3)
    //.....some logic
}

while( coins > 0 ) {
    casino();
    coins--;
}
```

Comment: That’s not what the question is asking.

Comment: Then just move the coins logic inside the casino function.
But if you only want to run it once, whats you point of having coins?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This does make sense and this loop runs until coins = 0. But what if I want to run it just once manually, every time. I am planning to add some logic inside the function which will also increase the number of coins if the user wins.